# Is there a python function to get `value_counts()` for pandas dataframe column with list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column `list`

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {"Trace" : [["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS"], 
                        ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"], 
                        ["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG"],
                        ["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["A-M", "B&M", "B&Q", "BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"],
                        ["BLOG", "BYPAS", "CIM"]]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

```
    Trace
0   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
1   [B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS]
2   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
3   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG]
4   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
5   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
6   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
7   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
8   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]
```

Is there a way to get the unique count of lists in the column, like `value_counts(normalize=True)` for hashable values in pandas?

```
                            Trace         Count    Percentage  
0   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]   
1   [B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS] 
2   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]  
3   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG]
```

Comment: `df['Trace'].apply(tuple).value_counts()` should do it. You have to make your list into `tuple` which is immutable and hashable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in comments by @Ch3ster you can use:

```
out=data['Trace'].map(tuple).value_counts().rename_axis(index='Trace').reset_index(name='Count')
out=out.assign(Trace=out['Trace'].map(list),Percentage=out['Count']/out['Count'].sum())
```

output of `out`:

```
    Trace                               Count   Percentage
0   [BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]                  4       0.444444
1   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS, CIM]   3       0.333333
2   [B&M, B&Q, BLOG, BYPAS]             1       0.111111
3   [A-M, B&M, B&Q, BLOG]               1       0.111111
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in comments by @Ch3ster

Using `apply`, `value_counts()` and `pd.concat`

```
data['Trace'].apply(tuple)


out = pd.concat([data['Trace'].value_counts(), 
                data['Trace'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)],axis=1, keys=('Counts','Percentage'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['Trace'].apply(tuple).value_counts()
or
df['Trace'].apply(tuple).value_counts(normalize=True)
```